# openxml remove all pictures in an excel file

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm developing a library that will get an excel and remove every image the excel contains.

I'm using the library DocumentFormat.OpenXml V. 2.7.2, I can find every image the document has on each sheet and I can delete every picture but when I check the output excel it has the same pictures the source one has, It has not deleted any picture.

My code is:

```
    public void RemoveImagesWithOpenXML(string sourceFilePath, string targetFilePath)
{
    SpreadsheetDocument excel = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(sourceFilePath, true);
    excel.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.ForEach(s =>
    {
        List<ImagePart> list = new List<ImagePart>();
        List<Drawing> drwdDeleteParts = new List<Drawing>();
        List<Drawing> drwParts = new List<Drawing>(s.RootElement.Descendants<Drawing>());
        foreach (var img in s.ImageParts)
        {
            string uri = img.Uri.ToString();
            list.Add(img);

            IEnumerable<Drawing> drawings = drwParts
                                                .Where(d => d.Descendants<Picture>()
                                                                .Any(p => p.BlipFill.Blip.Embed == s.GetIdOfPart(img)));
            foreach (var drawing in drawings)
            {
                if (drawing != null && !drwdDeleteParts.Contains(drawing)) drwdDeleteParts.Add(drawing);
            }
        }
        foreach (var d in drwdDeleteParts) d.Remove();
        s.DeleteParts(list);
    });
    excel.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
}
```

Comment: *The library throws a System.NullReferenceException exception.* ... where/when does it throw that. What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, none exception is thrown that was my mistake I have edited the question.